# Alfresco trying to get the siteService object

Tags: object, service, alfresco

I have no experience with Alfresco, I do know how to program however, so no problem there.

I am trying to do a minor edit to the /share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/share/imports/share-header.lib.js file to add a few menu elements to the share menu.

I want to list all the sites a user is a member of as seperate menu items for faster navigation and also remove the "my files" and "shared files" elements since they aren't being used (was the easy part).

After doing some searching I came across the siteService object which can do what I want to achieve so I added the following to the generateAppItems function.

```
function generateAppItems() {
.....
var sites = siteService.listUserSites(user.name); 
   for (var i=0; i<sites.length; i++)
   {
       var targetUrl = "site/" + sites[i].shortName + "/" + dashboard;
       appItems.push({
          id: "HEADER_SITE_" + sites[i].shortName.toUpperCase(),
          name: "alfresco/menus/AlfMenuBarItem",
          config: {
             id: "HEADER_SITE_" + sites[i].shortName.toUpperCase(),
             label: (sites[i].title) ? sites[i].title : sites[i].shortName,
             targetUrl: targetUrl
          }
       });
   }
.....
}
```

But now I get the following error

```
ReferenceError: "siteService" is not defined.
```

I have googled around but can't find anywhere how I should declare this elusive siteService object.

Comment: As per the [Alfresco JavaScript API docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/references/API-JS-rootscoped.html), the `siteService` JS object is only available to Repository (Alfresco webapp) scripts. It isn't available on the Share tier. Why not simply call one of the Alfresco webscripts (REST APIs) to get the list of sites for the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as @Gagravarr pointed out, you can't access the siteService through the share tier.

Instead you have to use the REST APIs of Alfresco.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

I ended up adding the following function

```
function getUserSites()
{
   // Call the repository for the site profile
   var json = remote.call("/api/people/" + encodeURIComponent(user.name) + "/sites");
   var userSites = null;
   if (json.status == 200)
   {
      // Create javascript objects from the repo response
      var obj = eval('(' + json + ')');
      if (obj)
      {
         userSites = obj;
      }
   }

   return userSites;
}
```

and changing the generateAppItems to

```
function generateAppItems() {
        var appItems = [
        {
            id: "HEADER_HOME",
            name: "alfresco/menus/AlfMenuBarItem",
            config: {
                id: "HEADER_HOME",
                label: "header.menu.home.label",
                targetUrl: "user/" + encodeURIComponent(user.name) + "/dashboard"
            }
        }
        ];

        var sites = getUserSites();

        if(sites != null) {
         for (var i=0; i<sites.length; i++)
         {
             var targetUrl = "site/" + sites[i].shortName + "/dashboard";
             appItems.push({
                id: "HEADER_SITE_" + sites[i].shortName.toUpperCase(),
                name: "alfresco/menus/AlfMenuBarItem",
                config: {
                   id: "HEADER_SITE_" + sites[i].shortName.toUpperCase(),
                   label: (sites[i].title) ? sites[i].title : sites[i].shortName,
                   targetUrl: targetUrl
                }
             });
         }
     } 

   appItems.push({
         id: "HEADER_SITES_MENU",
         name: "alfresco/header/AlfSitesMenu",
         config: {
            id: "HEADER_SITES_MENU",
            label: "header.menu.sites.label",
            currentSite: page.url.templateArgs.site,
            currentUser: user.name
         }
      },
      {
       id: "HEADER_TASKS",
       name: "alfresco/header/AlfMenuBarPopup",
       config: {
          id: "HEADER_TASKS",
          label: "header.menu.tasks.label",
          widgets: [
             {   
                name: "alfresco/menus/AlfMenuGroup",
                config: {
                   widgets: [
                      {
                         id: "HEADER_MY_TASKS",
                         name: "alfresco/header/AlfMenuItem",
                         config:
                         {
                            id: "HEADER_MY_TASKS",
                            label: "header.menu.mytasks.label",
                            iconClass: "alf-mytasks-icon",
                            targetUrl: "my-tasks#filter=workflows|active"
                         }
                      },
                      {
                         id: "HEADER_MY_WORKFLOWS",
                         name: "alfresco/header/AlfMenuItem",
                         config:
                         {
                            id: "HEADER_MY_WORKFLOWS",
                            label: "header.menu.myworkflows.label",
                            iconClass: "alf-myworkflows-icon",
                            targetUrl: "my-workflows#filter=workflows|active"
                         }
                      }
                   ]
                }
             }
          ]
       }
   });

   if (user.isAdmin || showRepositoryLink == "true")
   {
      appItems.push({
         id: "HEADER_REPOSITORY",
         name: "alfresco/menus/AlfMenuBarItem",
         config: {
            id: "HEADER_REPOSITORY",
            label: "header.menu.repository.label",
            targetUrl: "repository"
         }
      });
   }
   if (user.isAdmin)
   {
      appItems.push({
         id: "HEADER_ADMIN_CONSOLE",
         name: "alfresco/menus/AlfMenuBarItem",
         config: {
            id: "HEADER_ADMIN_CONSOLE",
            label: "header.menu.admin.label",
            targetUrl: "console/admin-console/application"
         }
      });
   }
   return appItems;
}
```

This will result in removing the MY FILES and SHARED FILES from the share header menu and adding all the sites the user is a member of as menu items for faster navigation.